# What game has this black main menu?

Tags: game-identification

I saw this picture of a game in a meme. it really looks familiar but i can't remember anything. does anyone know the game and platform?

[image]

Comment: Oh, man. I *heard* this screenshot.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

That is the main menu for the game Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas!
Makes me oddly nostalgic.

Answer (score 28):

Looks like [GTA San Andreas](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiueLmg5oUSSY92xOSr5zjr0VJIMf7lJBke28Le9akcq2WAcaTRUT6k61L0onWio1G5j9g2c6_1uxbacY_1-4M72Rr9AvAmchHxPBV2da0xp6RRCu5VpsnfktqqMemmWmB5gMtMKtcP138pqJzdeuDdVYhrbZ7lZEORUiKAG55G8a0KShClL3V_1Ypy6KMnXTe2nv_1ZboT1RR4QSeHCf1qU3mcyIdRnXUDGhw7GWoZ4WIz1jbSBunqVkNkOZ8BnbDto5BUefyQk-wFIxyFaSNs6F73n8X0M0BCJ3A2i5u3yFtqqtOLnsIkU4mVFksdZ4PZJ8KGpJTMjGAme8wIZ2FQfL5aaO5DjcA) according to google reverse image search.

[This video](https://youtu.be/TQEVzgWFXu0?t=209) (the next ~5 seconds) provides a proof for the menu being from GTA San Andreas.